# How to run one specific test from DynamicData with visual studio test explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using [DataTestMethod] with [DynamicData] like explained here: https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm

Now to fix one failing test, I'd like to debug only this one, not all the cases.

For example:

```
[TestClass]
public class MathTests
{
    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(Data), DynamicDataSourceType.Property)]
    public void Test_Add_DynamicData_Property(int a, int b, int expected)
    {
        var actual = MathHelper.Add(a, b);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Data
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[] { 1, 1, 2 };
            yield return new object[] { 12, 30, 42 };
            yield return new object[] { 14, 1, 15 };
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to debug only Test_Add_DynamicData_Property(12, 30, 42) .

Of course, I could :

- Create a separated TestMethod for this case.
- Comment out the other lines from Data.

I'm looking for a solution that don't imply that I will need to revert something later (with the risk to forget).

Comment: I don't think MSTest v2 provide a way to run a single test. You should open an issue on their GitHub repository to suggest this feature. Note that XUnit and NUnit offer this feature.